# How to post on group wall of facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post on group wall. I have permission of "user_groups" and "publish_stream". and also access_token.

and here is my code:

```
                try{
            $statusUpdate = $this->facebook->api('/'.$group_id.'/feed', 'post',
                 array(
                'name' => stripslashes($productname),
                //'caption'=>$caption,
                'message' => $message,
                'description' => $description,
                'picture' => $picture,
                'link'=>$link));

                    $postid =  $statusUpdate['id']; // return id


            } catch (Exception $e){
                        $postid = 0;
                    }
                    return $postid; // return id
    }
```

When I run this code I get a return id which was the page id. but nothing post on my group wall. how to solve this?

Comment: in the sample code your variable name says, $page_id. you need to pass the group_id. If the create is successful, you get the ID of the new post.

Comment: its my mistake. it is a group id. and after posting I get the id. which was exactly same as the group id. but nothing is posted on group wall.

Comment: imm, just try hardcode the group_id and lets see its posting to group or not

Comment: I tried with hardcode  group id . but still no result. I saw other results of same category. but did not get any solution.

Comment: finally it work for me. Its not this function problem. I just give another permission "manage_pages" and it work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me to post to a facebook page.

1. Get FB page access token ($value['access_token']) and its page id ($value['id'])
2. Populate the $params array
3. use the FB API to post your message 3.

This is a snippet

```
foreach ($pages as $key => $value) {
   $params = array(
      'access_token' => $value['access_token'],
       'message' => $message
    );
    // ask facebook api to post the message to the selected page
    $facebook->api()->api( "/" . $value['id'] . "/feed", 'POST', $params );
}
```

Comment: Will this code works to post on group wall which we dont own but we are member of it..?

basically, Is it possible to post on groups using fb api?